# How to render Handlebars markup from a Liquid template (Jekyll)

Tags: handlebars.js, jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll for our blog and rendering Handlebars templates is a pain. We have to escape like so:

```
{% highlight html %}
  <div>{{"{{code"}}}}</div>
{% endhighlight %}
```

It's fugly. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I was using the same... so ugly

Answer (score 24):

I found the answer:

```
{% highlight html %}
{% raw %}
  <div>{{code}}</div>
{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: This works for inline code too (at least with octopress): {% raw %}`oh {{hi}}`{% endraw %}