# Jekyll and EmberJS conflicts?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, jekyll, liquid

Does anyone have insight into using Jekyll with an EmberJS project and if it poses problems with either framework since they use the double curly brace syntax for variables such as {{ title }}.

I just wanted to check to see if anyone had some inside info before starting a large environment build out with Jekyll and EmberJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember and Jekyll uses the same syntax to inject variables in the templates.

- Jekyll uses the Liquid template engine. In this system, you use `{{variable}}` to display the content of a `variable`, usually defined in the font-matter of the page (or the site configuration).
- Ember uses Handlebars as template engine by default, with Ember/Handlebars, you use `{{variable}}` to access the `variable` attribute or property of the Controller (or Model).

This must be the source of the conflict. , it can be avoided by surrounding the Handlebars code with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` tags. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209942/how-to-render-handlebars-markup-from-a-liquid-template-jekyll) for details:

```
{% raw %}
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
    <div>{{title}}</div>
  </script>
{% endraw %}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Pablo! also recently found this: github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers)

Comment: Glad to help. [Liquid for Designers](http://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers)